# Joomla: Dealing with Sub menus

Tags: drop-down-menu, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

How do you hide sub menus (drop down) for a specific menu. For instance I have 3 menus; Soccer, Basketball, and Football. When I hover on the soccer menu, I see articles named Messi, Ronaldo and Neymar drop down. I hover on the Basketball menu, I see Lebron, Durant, and Kobe. When i hover over the football menu, i see RG3, Wilson, and Manning. I want to get it such that when I hover on the soccer menu, I can't see any of the articles in a drop down menu. I want to get it just for the soccer menu, but the others should still have drop down menus when hovered on.

Comment: do you mean, not drop down menus for soccer main menu, but when you click on it, it should display all the articles related to soccer?

Comment: No, i don't want to see a drop down menu when hovered on. Is there a way to hide it? I don't wanna unpublish the articles as well.

Comment: you should change all your articles related to Messi, ronaldo and neymar to the top menu's category, then, delete or unpublish those child menus(Messi, ronaldo and neymar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `mod_menu` module, you have to create a template override to `templates/your_template/html/mod_menu/default.php` and add this code at the beginning of: `foreach ($list as $i => &$item) { ... }`

```
$parent_id = 779;
if($item->id == $parent_id) { $item->deeper = null; }
$this_parent = $item->parent_id;
while ($this_parent != 1) {
    if($this_parent == $parent_id) continue 2;
    foreach ($list as $parent_search) {
        if($parent_search->id == $this_parent) {
            $this_parent = $parent_search->parent_id;
        }
    }
}
```

So it will check if parent has the specified id and skip all children.
You could also extend it using `in_array()` for multiple ids.

Reference: [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the Module Manager for that specific menu.  There is a drop down for "Start Level" and "End Level".  Just set them both to "1" and only the top level items will be displayed.